# Setup google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I'm new to google analytics. And I need some help to set it up.

I'll explain all parts of this application.

- First I got the company. That page is only a regular site with some information, contact and product information. It have nothing to do with the customers. Not more then they share the url in some way.
- - The companys subdomains is customers. On every customer there is the main application.
- - - The customers subdomains is some other applications.

For an example.
www.myCompany.com

Customers:

1. - www.customer1.myCompany.com
   - www.subApplication1.customer1.myCompany.com
2. - www.customer2.myCompany.com
   - www.subApplication1.customer2.myCompany.com
   - www.subApplication2.customer2.myCompany.com
3. - www.customer3.myCompany.com
   - www.subApplication1.customer3.myCompany.com
   - www.subApplication2.customer3.myCompany.com

**What I don't want to:**

I don't want *myCompany.com* to share any data with any customers/subdomains.

I don' want *customer.myCompany.com* to share any data with *subApplication.customer.myCompany.com*

I don' want *subApplication1.customer1.myCompany.com*, *subApplication2.customer1.myCompany.com*, *subApplication3.customer1.myCompany.com* to share any data.

**What I want to:**

- It would been nice if it was possible to both see data filtered on each customer, eg. see customers own activity/data for *customer1.myCompany.com*. And own activity/data for *customer2.myCompany.com*
- Share on application (url). Eg. *customer1.myCompany.com*, *customer2.myCompany.com*, *customer3.myCompany.com* and so on. And eg. *mobile.customer1.myCompany.com*, *mobile.customer2.myCompany.com*, *mobile.customer3.myCompany.com*.

What I understands I'll use filter and views for this. But should I generate different tracking code's for each application (main application, subapplication1, subapplication 2....)? At least myCompany should have it's own? Because that homepage have nothing to do with the customers.

Or should I use tag for this?

Answer (score 1):

Here goes my suggestion: 
You can use different Properties to separate your domain from your subdomains. 
So the first property would get data just from www.myCompany.com and would have it's own tracking code. 
The second one, with its own tracking code as well, would have data from all of your sub domais. To separate the data, you can create views with the following filters:
- the first view would include just the subdomain customer[1-9].myCompany.com 
- the following views could have filters to separate the applications from each other or to include all of them in one, remember that you can create just 50 views for Property.  
Hope I've helped.